# Installing Perl DBI on amazon instance

Tags: perl, dbi

I have perl script which uses DBI e. g

```
use DBI;
```

When I execute the script I get the following error :

```
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./install.pl line 15.
```

## Tried to install DBI:

a) `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'`

```
 failed with YAML error
```

b) `sudo apt-get install libyaml-perl`

c) re-run a)
    `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'`

d) c) failed so tried this way

```
`sudo cpan DBI
```

In both step d) & d) I get following errors at the end:

```
 Writing Makefile for DBI
Writing MYMETA.yml
  TIMB/DBI-1.627.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I do also need to install `DBD::mysql;`

System info:
 `per -v : (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`

## Edit:

Further I installed gcc by
    `sudo apt-get install gcc`

and  `cc -v` is now

`.....Thread model: posix  gcc version 4.6.3 .......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After some googling I found this link about `make` failure on [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=692890)

And post#3  worked for me

1. `sudo apt-get install libyaml-perl`
2. `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'`

## Install DBI

(apart from the step in above question)

a) `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool gdb`

b) `sudo cpan DBI`

## install DBD::mysql

a) `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

b) `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

c) `sudo cpan DBD::mysql`

I need all of the above steps as I have fresh instance